# Jquery .remove() does not update DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to remove an element form the DOM using the `.remove()` jQuery method

Basically i am parsing a list and removing certain elements. Then right after, i reparse the list for some treatment for the rest of the elements.

But a simple printout of the size of the list gives me the impression that the elements to be filtered out were not removed

```
$list = $(".elements_list");
alert( $list.size());
$list.each(function(){
  if ( $(this).data("quantity") == 0)
  {
    $(this).slideUp(1000,function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
});
change_background_colors();
```

Right after this treatment, i call another function that has the following code in the beginning:

```
function change_background_colors() {    
  $list = $(".elements_list");
  alert($list.size());
  ...
}
```

I get the same size of the list before and after removing elements...

Is there something wrong in my approach ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by context ? Sorry, i am new to jQuery/Javascript...

Comment: he means check the value of `this` when you go to remove.

Comment: If you call that before animation is done the element is still there. Show us where you put the second size check

Comment: I edited my question to show where i am putting the size alerts

Answer (score 1):

The element is not removed until after 1000 milliseconds pass and the animation completes. Wait until then to count the elements.

edit: here's the more complicated way to delay till all animates complete:

```
$list = $(".elements_list");
var n = 0;
$list.each(function(){
  if ( $(this).data("quantity") == 0) {
    n = n + 1; // one more callback to wait for
    $(this).slideUp(1000,function(){
      $(this).remove();
      n = n-1;
      checkIfAllDone();
    });
  }
});
function checkIfAllDone(){
  if(n===0){ // be sure that n was declared in the same scope as this function
    change_background_colors();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather point (explain) OP to count the elements inside the animate callback - after the *remove*...

Comment: if you see the changes in the code, you would see that i am printing out the size outside of the slideUp callback.

Comment: How to wait for all the slideUps to finish ?

Answer (score 1):

if you call the size alert in a setTimeOut function you will see

```
$list = $(".elements_list");
alert($list.size());
$list.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data("quantity") == 0) {
        $(this).slideUp(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();

        });
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $list = $(".elements_list");
    alert($list.size());
}, 2000);
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/upkkLq2m/2/

Comment: I suggest using this approach to delay the second count because it's simpler than my edit